# CMAKE <LINK_LIBRARIES> separated by spaces not commas in linker command

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm trying to get CMake to use a custom compiler to build some code. I've setup a cmake toolchain file that works great for everything besides linking in static libraries.
The linker requires all libraries to be passed using a -library=example.lib,example2.lib. Cmake seems to default to using spaces to separate libraries but this linker won't take it.
Here is my linker call example from my toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${LINKER} <OBJECTS> -library=<LINK_LIBRARIES> <LINK_FLAGS> -output=<TARGET>")
```

This produces everything except the librarys are passed like this:

```
-library= example1.lib example2.lib
```

Not this:

```
-library=example1.lib,example2.lib
```

How can I get CMake to separate the <LINK_LIBRARIES> variable with commas not spaces? It even puts one between the -library= and the first lib.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html